# Qsub leads to script not working: "Command not found"

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, qsub

I am running a script "example.sh" which accepts 5 command-line arguments.

This works fine:

```
./example.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

and it returns a file result1.txt

Now when I try running it on the SGE cluster (with or without "./"):

```
qsub ./example.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

This does not result in any output.

In the example.sh.eXXXXXXX file, I get:

```
arg1=1: Command not found.
arg2=2: Command not found.
...
and so on.
```

I am not sure why it does not work with the qsub command. I also inserted a

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

at the top of my script. I've been tweaking stuff for a while, trying different things I have found on stackoverflow and the web, but no success thus far (I have tried the -S and -F flags). Any suggestions are appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I googled a little bit and two things come in mind: 1. Are you sure that the sun grid provides a `bash`? (I saw lots of `csh` samples. Syntax of `csh` is a little bit different from that of `bash`.) 2. I couldn't find any sample with additional command line arguments which makes me suspicious. The man entry `qsub [ options ] [ command | -- [ command_args ]]` looks like whether this is not supported. Solution is easy: wrap your script call _with_ arguments into a new script. (What I suggest here I've learnt in the last half hour. If you get a serious answer I will erase this comment.)

Answer (score 1):

`qsub` won't accept your shell script's arguments like that, but either of these will work:

1) Put `./example.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5` into another script, e.g. `command.sh`, and then run `qsub command.sh`.

2) Pipe your full command into `qsub` as standard input, e.g.: `echo ./example.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 | qsub`.